# Data displayed as undefined on Ajax Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I got stuck to parsing the json data to html, but got the undefined value.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/rest/api/kkb/detail/?key=39E62227E3294114BE8EADF3B6D2F06E&id=4",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].start);
  }
    success: function (response) {
        var trHTML = '';
       $.each(response, function (i, item) {
           trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.year + '</td><td>' + item.period + '</td></tr>';
       });
       $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
    },

    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
};
getUserData();
```

the result from the API url is:

```
{"status":true,
 "message":"Detail Kkb",
 "data": { "kkb": { "id":"4",
                    "year":"2014",
                    "periode":"S-I",
                    "name":"TWA Joe Som"
                   }
          }
}
```

and the html code: `<table id="records_table"></table>`

but is not working, it said undefined. when i check on log data in firebug, the data loaded. Really appreciate for any help

Comment: why do u have two success functions? what is the first one for?

Comment: also you are iterating but your response is not big enough for iteration; Is there more to your responsel; if so, please post that too so that we can help

Comment: console wt is printing can u print me or upload pic

Comment: Thanks all for the reply, the first one success function for the content length, i tried to use this for count the json data and planning to display as number on html :(

Comment: did u get the result iam post answer below see u can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var response= [{"status":true,"message":"Detail Kkb","data":{"kkb":{"id":"4","year":"2014","periode":"S-I","name":"TWA Joe Som"}}}];
 var trHTML = '';
       $.each(response, function (i, item) {
           trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.data.kkb.name + '</td><td>' + item.data.kkb.year + '</td><td>' + item.data.kkb.period + '</td></tr>';
       });
       console.log(trHTML);
       $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr id="records_table"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I got it but it not displaying on my html table (on cosole only). Within your code, how to implement this to mine (using ajax). I am really new to JSON :(

Comment: ajax  success function use this one that iam use take content of u uploaded content,insted of console add this  $('#records_table').append(trHTML);

Comment: Tried it but got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'kkb' of undefined

Comment: the result from the API url is:u posted result only i tried          var trHTML = '';
       $.each(response, function (i, item) {
           trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.data.kkb.name + '</td><td>' + item.data.kkb.year + '</td><td>' + item.data.kkb.period + '</td></tr>';
       }); use this paste at success function

Comment: Typo on my side, the error fixed. but the data still not showing on html page after using $('#records_table').append(trHTML);

Comment: can u see the above answer ,wt printing in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159370/discussion-between-jeevanswamy21-and-da-root).

Comment: I am on chat now