# .on("click") Not appending to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, append

I am making a gif generator, the goal being to dynamically create clickable buttons that will then dynamically add 10 gifs from the search term to the page. On click is returning the console log, but will not add divs with gif images and rating to the page.

HTML

```
<form id="killer-form">
    <label for="killer-input">Add a serial killer:</label>
    <input type="text" id="killer-input"><br>
    <input id="killer-add-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="append-img-div"></div>
```

JS

```
var killersGifs = {

    killerSearches: ["Freddy", "Jason", "Pennywise", "Ghost Face", "American Mary", "Chucky", "Bride of Chucky", "Candyman", "Cujo", "Hannibal", "Leatherface", "Michael Meyers", "Norman Bates", "Pinhead"],

    buttonLoop: function() {
        for (var b = 0; b < killersGifs.killerSearches.length - 1; b++) {
            var buttonM = $("<button class='dynGen'>").text(killersGifs.killerSearches[b]).attr("data-index", killersGifs.killerSearches[b]);
            $("#buttons").append(buttonM);
        }
    },

    divLoop: function(event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < killersGifs.killerSearches.length - 1; i++) {
            //console.log(this.killerSearches[i]);
            //var newDiv = $("<div class='gif-div'>");
            var killer = killersGifs.killerSearches[i];
            var queryURL = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=B26sstJns2pZuNT5HiJpqS5FV8Su1sDd&q=" + killer + "&limit=10"


            //console.log(queryURL);
            $.ajax({
                url: queryURL,
                method: "GET"
            }).done(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
                for (var x = 0; x < response.length - 1; x++) {

                    var respData = response[x].data;
                    var image = respData.images.fixed_height_small_still.url;
                    var rating = respData.rating;

                    var dynDiv = $("<div class='dyn-div'>");
                    var killerImg = $("<img>");

                    killerImg.attr("src", image);
                    killerImg.attr("alt", "Serial Killer still frame of gif");

                    dynDiv.append("Rating: " + rating);
                    dynDiv.append(image);


                    $("#append-img-div").prepend(dynDiv);

                };

            });

        };
    },

    userPush: function () {
        var userInput = $("input[type='text']").val().trim();
        console.log(userInput);
        killersGifs.killerSearches.push(userInput);
        var buttonU = $("<button class='dynGen'>").text(userInput).attr("data-index", userInput);
        $("#buttons").append(buttonU);
        console.log(killersGifs.killerSearches);
    }

};

killersGifs.buttonLoop();

$("#killer-add-submit").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    killersGifs.userPush();
   });

$(document).on("click", "button.dynGen", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#append-img-div").empty();
    killersGifs.divLoop(event);
});
```

Clicking a button should return 10 images (still gifs) related to that word.

The `console.log` runs on click, but it is console logging an array of 10 for all 13 words as opposed to one array for the word clicked on.

Comment: Hi, what errors you get?

Comment: No errors logging in the console.

Comment: console.log(response); can upload this data or pic

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0J3WH - This was the response when I clicked on Chucky- Sorry, I just got what you were asking. Just a sec

Comment: Change `var respData = response.data;` to `var respData = response[x].data;` so you will not be executing same operation with same data multiple times

Comment: A bit lost. You have an array `killerSearches` that has some pre filled items, and user push something new in this array. In another function you fall into a loop and traverse all items in `killerSearches` array and call ajax?

Comment: And you most use this line: `var killer = killersGifs.killerSearches[i];` upper than this line: `var queryURL = "h...`

Comment: console.log(response) is in the code just below .done (in the ajax method). When I add console.log(response) outside of .done, it returns an error stating response is not defined. https://imgur.com/sEWnaO3

Comment: @ofc becuse outside of `done`, `responsive` is not defined

Comment: I wonder how you wont get error about `killer` is `undefined` because after you used `killer` you defined it. You used `killer` in `queryURL` while its wrong

Comment: I believe my error is in the loop and ajax area. Yes, on clicking submit, I am grabbing user text from the input text area and pushing to the killerSearched array to ultimately add a new clickable button set to the user text. (I have completed this code since posting the question).

Comment: I have changed var respData = response.data; to var respData = response[x].data; and I moved the killer variable to be defined prior to the queryURL variable being defined.

Comment: imgur.com/sEWnaO3  in this image show the wt is inside array show that pic

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vU6Qv And it is returning one array for every item in the killerSearches array, not one array for the button being clicked

Comment: remove the data it will work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386213/data-displayed-as-undefined-on-ajax-json/47386393#47386393

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` is an Object.

`response.length` is an undefined.

`response.data` is an Array.

If you want image also, Then you should append `killerImg` also.

```js
var killersGifs = {

  killerSearches: ["Freddy", "Jason", "Pennywise", "Ghost Face", "American Mary", "Chucky", "Bride of Chucky", "Candyman", "Cujo", "Hannibal", "Leatherface", "Michael Meyers", "Norman Bates", "Pinhead"],

  buttonLoop: function() {
    for (var b = 0; b < killersGifs.killerSearches.length - 1; b++) {
      var buttonM = $("<button class='dynGen'>").text(killersGifs.killerSearches[b]).attr("data-index", killersGifs.killerSearches[b]);
      $("#buttons").append(buttonM);
    }
  },

  divLoop: function(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < killersGifs.killerSearches.length - 1; i++) {
      //console.log(this.killerSearches[i]);
      //var newDiv = $("<div class='gif-div'>");
      var queryURL = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=B26sstJns2pZuNT5HiJpqS5FV8Su1sDd&q=" + killer + "&limit=10"

      var killer = killersGifs.killerSearches[i];
      //console.log(queryURL);
      $.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: "GET"
      }).done(function(response) {
//            console.log(response.data.length);
        for (var x = 0; x < response.data.length - 1; x++) {
          var respData = response.data[x];
          var image = respData.images.fixed_height_small_still.url;
          var rating = respData.rating;

          var dynDiv = $("<div class='dyn-div'></div>");
          var killerImg = $("<img>");

          killerImg.attr("src", image);
          killerImg.attr("alt", "Serial Killer still frame of gif");

          dynDiv.append("Rating: " + rating);
          dynDiv.append(image);


          $("#append-img-div").prepend($(dynDiv).append($(killerImg)));

        };

      });

    };
  },

  userPush: function() {
    var userInput = $("input[type='text']").val().trim();
    console.log(userInput);
    killersGifs.killerSearches.push(userInput);
    console.log(killersGifs.killerSearches);
  }

};

killersGifs.buttonLoop();

$("#killer-add-submit").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  killersGifs.userPush();
});

$(document).on("click", "button.dynGen", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#append-img-div").empty();
  killersGifs.divLoop(event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="buttons"></div>

<form id="killer-form">
  <label for="killer-input">Add a serial killer:</label>
  <input type="text" id="killer-input"><br>
  <input id="killer-add-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="append-img-div"></div>
```

Comment: That is getting it on the page. Thank you!

Comment: This is wrong `dynDiv.append(image);` use this one `dynDiv.append(killerImg);`

Comment: @ColinCline That i don't know why she want that.

Comment: I totally noticed that just a couple seconds ago >_<